How to make NextJS work properly with fetch and headers?
I have a NextJS application, playing around with the official tutorials.
They show how to fetch data from an API together with an API-Key as authorization header. But TypeScript can't compile the code due to:

TS2769: No overload matches this call.

How to fix that?
Here is the code:
export async function getPosts(lang: string) {
    const res = await fetch(url + lang, {
        headers: {
            authorization: process.env.API_KEY,
        },
    })

    return res.json()
}


process.env.API_KEY is of type string | undefined. It's undefined because you might forget to add it to .env file. the headers property expects Record<string, string>. or [string, string][] | Headers
You need to tell TypeScript that this env variable is not undefined by one of:

Non-null assertion: process.env.API_KEY!
check before:

export async function getPosts(lang: string) {
   const API_KEY = process.env.API_KEY;

   if (!API_KEY) {
       throw new Error("You forgot to add API_KEY to .env file")
   }


    const res = await fetch(url + lang, {
        headers: {
            authorization: API_KEY,
        },
    })

    return res.json()
}

